# getting "Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError:"on importing Pywhatkit in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I was making a program which needed pywhatkit module to send messages.I was running this on PythonAnywhere but I don't think that is the one that is causing the problem.

Here is the code:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91**********","hi",16,50)
```

But after importing pywhatkit ,I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    s.connect('/tmp/.X11-unix/X%d' % dno)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code2d/pyw.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    s.connect('/tmp/.X11-unix/X%d' % dno)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code2d/pyw.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.main import print_sleep_time, check_window, sendwhatmsg, sendwhatmsg_to_group, sendwhatmsg_instantly, info, playonyt, search
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pywhatkit/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    return mod.get_socket(dname, host, dno)
  File "/home/code2d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 78, in get_socket
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>>
```

So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: does this `/tmp/.X11-unix/X%d` exists on your computer?

Comment: no  i guess that file is only there for unix os users;mine is Windows

Comment: Is that present on pythonanywhere? If not then you have setup your environment properly.

Comment: no the file is not there in python anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyWhatKit requires Chrome or any other browser with UI, i.e. you can't use it on servers as they use browsers in headless mode. Please consider using selenium.